# Error(-10): The app is not owned by any user on this device

Tags: android, in-app-update

I implement the in-app update and it works good, but when I have a new Google account that never download my app from play store , the in-app update failed by app not owned error "Install Error(-10): The app is not owned by any user on this device" Any idea why?

Comment: did you know what happen ?  I get the same error

Comment: Anyone found what's wrong? I am also stuck at same error

Answer (score 2):

Actually you will insta same application from playstore once and uninstall it

Now you can install the debug or signed apk now in-app update screen will work.

Mainly Android 11 facing this issue,

Comment: Thank you. I hadn't known how to solve it for days. I installed the application for the first time from Playstore and then from Android Studio with a lower version and the update started immediately.